# Access list with two pcs and two routers

Tags: packet-tracer, acl

I have Router0, on G0/0 connected PC0 with ip192.168.1.2 /24, on Router1 on G0/1.3 connected PC1 with network 192.168.3.2 /24. I need PC0 to be able to ping PC1 and PC1 cannot ping PC0.

I have tried different access lists but nothing works for me. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Access lists have nothing to do with it (ACLs *filter* traffic and are not used for forwarding). Most likely, the routers miss a route to the respective remote network.